# How to invoke the servlets correctly if .html files are placed inside a folder within Web Content?

Tags: java, html, servlets, tomcat7, eclipse-luna

I am able to invoke the servlets correctly if I place the ***.html files*** under ***Web-Content*** and fail to invoke the servlets if I place them after creating a new folder within Web-Content?

[image: Package Explorer Tree Structure]

The one selected(***in blue***) when run is able to invoke the specified servlet.
But for the 2 files placed ***under folder javaTpoint***, after running these files, ***Error 404 renders***.
If I move to the location where the selected one is, then the case works fine.

I have to create the folders so as to better streamline the file in web applcn.

Comment: Do you mean you can't access the requestDispatcherLogin.html and the other html file under javaTpoint page?

Comment: Would I be right in guessing that in addition to having the folder javaTpoint you mapped a servlet to `javaTpoint/*`?

Comment: the servlet class is within a package in src. In the screenshot attached, validatePasswordRequestDispacther.html works fine. But if i move this file to be within javaTpoint folder, clicking the submit button gives  Error 404.

Comment: @developerwjk : You are right! But i happened to go through your comment after solving it of my own. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, when the .html files were placed within the ***WebContent,*** and not within a ***folder*** inside ***WebContent***, the ***mappings*** corresponding to the servlet in **web.xml** was as mentioned below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sendRedirect1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.javatpoint.MySearcherOnSendRedirect</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sendRedirect1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/searchOnSendRedirect</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

where the ***/searchOnSendRedirect*** within

```
<url-pattern>/searchOnSendRedirect</url-pattern>
```

is pointing to the servlet invoked when pressing the submit button in a form element in a .html file

```
<form action="searchOnSendRedirect">
```

Now, whenever we create a folder within WebContent and place some .html files, the ***url-pattern***
needs to be changed as reflected below:

```
<url-pattern>/javaTpoint/searchOnSendRedirect</url-pattern>
```

where ***javaTpoint*** is the name of the folder created within WebContent.